# SQL Subqueries as own column

Tags: sql

consider this. My Table looks something like this

```
ID1   |   ID2   |    Value   |
1          1         Three
1          2         Random
1          3         Words
2          1         Not
2          2         So
2          3         Random
3          1         Why
3          2         No
3          3         Yes
```

And my output should look like

```
ID   |   Value1   |   Value2   |   Value3
1    |     Three  |    Random  |      Words
2    |     Not    |    So      |      Random
3    |     Why    |    No      |      Yes
```

What am I looking for? I don't need a solution, just the concept to look for as I am lost. Thank you.

Comment: The word you want is PIVOT. That said, doing it may be trivial or cumbersome depending on which DBMS you are using

Comment: Is the number of columns in output fixed ? I mean, you know how many different values `ID1` can have ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak Yes the output is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is `PIVOT` or `TRANSPOSE`. Try searching for "Convert Rows to Columns" in google.

In oracle, your PIVOT  query would be as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ID1 ID, VALUE
        FROM   MY_TABLE)
PIVOT  (MIN(VALUE) AS VALUE FOR (ID2) IN ('1' ,'2','3'));
```

Here is a [site for reference](http://oracletuts.net/sql/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT ID1 As 'ID',
MAX(IF(ID2=1 ,Value,null)) AS 'Value1',
MAX(IF(ID2=2,Value,null)) AS 'Value2',
MAX(IF(ID2=3,Value,null)) AS 'Value3'
FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID1;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT ID1 AS 'ID', 
[1] AS 'Value1', 
[2] AS 'Value2', 
[3] AS 'Value3'
FROM (
SELECT ID1,ID2,Value
FROM MyTable) x
PIVOT(
MAX(Value)
FOR ID2 IN ([1],[2],[3]) 
) p
```

**[FIND SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b3c/37)**